# linux, python3: syntax error on commandline but not in ipython %run command

Tags: linux, python-3.x, matplotlib

This simple code generates a syntax error on line 6 item "`('"
when run as # ./main.py from commandline

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create a top-level Figure object
# with some optional customizations
fig = plt.figure('Population density',figsize=(5./2.254,5./2.254),facecolor='red',edgecolor='green')

# creating an Axes object containing axex and the rest
# we plot on the ax object of class Axes
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# we plot data with ax.plot

x = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
line_cosh, = ax.plot(x, np.cosh(x))
line_quad, = ax.plot(x, 1+x**2/2)
plt.show()
```

---

except when run in ipython using %run, the plot appears

---

ipython through %run

Question: where is the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

add

## !/usr/bin/env python

to top of python scripts run from command line in linux